# Understanding Results of ANOVA

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

I ran a two-factor ANOVA, where I'm looking at the time it takes to type a word. The data was split up by what type of task it took place in (6 tasks) and where the word was (outside/middle). For each category, there were 272 subjects. I believe `Column` corresponds to each of the 6 tasks, and `Sample` refers to outside vs middle.

I don't understand how to interpret the p-value. I know 2 of them are significant, assuming p < 0.05 is significant. But what is it saying is significant?

```
+---------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Source of Variation |     SS      |  df  |     MS      |      F      |    P-value    |   F-crit    |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| Sample              | 23315322.12 |    1 | 23315322.12 | 289.8222677 | 0             | 3.844319706 |
| Columns             | 759572.8972 |    5 | 151914.5794 | 1.888381712 | 0.09300516791 | 2.216848646 |
| Interaction         | 903591.9503 |    5 | 180718.3901 | 2.246428908 | 0.0472256737  | 2.216848646 |
| Within              | 261613533.5 | 3252 | 80446.96603 |             |               |             |
+---------------------+-------------+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this table?

Comment: I don't understand how to interpret the p-value. I know 2 of them are significant, assuming p < 0.05 is significant. But what is it saying is significant?

Comment: You should edit your question to be more precise, because it is not clear what is not clear for you with ANOVA.

Comment: It means that there is a significant effect of Sample and Interaction and not of Columns. What is not clear for you with this result? (I ask because if you state your problem more precisely you have a greater chance of getting an answer that would actually be valuable for you.)

Comment: Thanks. I've added further clarification. What exactly are the Samples, Columns, and Interactions?

Comment: This is something that **you** should tell us :) `Samples` and `Columns` are names of some variables that are included in the ANOVA model. You should know what they are, we do not have your data.

Comment: It seems that you did not give the ANOVA program labels for the two variables, but accepted the default. There is no way anyone can help without seeing how you entered the data and knowing the details of whatever program you used.

Comment: This was done using XLMiner Analysis Toolpak for Google Sheets, which doesn't give you that option. The columns are each of the 6 tasks. In row 2 and row 273,  have the location, Inside/Outside, which I guess is Sample. I'll add that